# Redirect user after registration

Tags: redirection, forms

I am trying to redirect new users after registration depending on values saved in $_SESSION. I use ajax for registration form submission and `hook_user_insert` fro redirect

```
function MYMODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category){
global $user;
if(isset($_SESSION['VAR']) && !$user->uid){
    drupal_goto('path/to/somewhere');

}
```

Once form is submitted I receive alert `AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally` and page html code. What should I change to make redirect working?

Comment: The redirect code looks good imo. Is a user created? If not, I suspect the ajax you used to manipulate submission threw an error and the redirect wasn't even executed.

Comment: Yes. I see user but he has no role (I use autoassignrole module) and never accessed

Answer (score 1):

You should alter the register form and set new redirect value.

```
function MYMODULE_user_register_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/somewhere';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href="your_location";
</script>
```

from your ajax callback. Hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

In case of ajax `drupal_goto` doesn't work. I found solution [here](http://dropbucket.org/node/1236). But it requires custom form submit function.

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
$form['#submit'][0] = 'MYMODULE_user_register_form_submit';

}
```

And to make things work copied code of legacy function from `user` module